# Prove that $\mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is another question:

> **Question.** Prove that $\mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = 0 $.

Where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are vectors, "$\times$" denotes the cross product, and "$\cdot$" is the dot product.

Here if I assume that $\mathbf{A}$ lies on the $x$ axis then there are three possibilities for $\mathbf{B}$: it lies on the $x$ axis, or on the $y$ axis, or on the $z$ axis.

Therefore, there are two ways that this question can have an answer $= 0$.

1. If $\mathbf{B}$ lies on the $y$ or $z$ axes, then $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C} = 0$ since then then would be perpendicular to each other.
2. If $\mathbf{B}$ lies on the $x$ axis, then $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}$ is already parallel and we get $= \mathbf{0}$. Thus $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{0} = 0$.

The Textbook uses point 1 as the right answer. Can both be correct?

**Edit:** Exact textbook quote:<sup>[1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWdZz.jpg)</sup>

> $\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{A}$. Now, the dot product of two perpendicular vectors is zero. Hence
>
> $$ \mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = 0. $$

Comment: is it dot product?

Comment: @Algebrology Yes. Ofc

Comment: Why can't $B$ be a vector like $(1,14,-13)$, which lies in none of the axis?

Comment: @S.M.T "*Textbook uses point 1*" $\;-\;$ Can you quote the relevant part from the textbook literally? What you wrote doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Is this in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble We are allowed to use it. But if you’re asking if why I have worsen X,Y,Z axis. It is an assumption for my Q.

Comment: The claim is trivial if you know that $\;\vec A\times \vec B\;$ is always a vector perpendicular, or normal or orthogonal, to both $\;\vec A\,,\,\,\vec B\; $ ...

Comment: @S.M.T There is no mention of $X,Y,Z$ in the book, and no relationship to your "*point 1*" whatsoever. Besides, the picture shows the entire proof. Is there something not clear about it, or are you disputing it, or are you asking about something entirely else?

Comment: @dxiv If the solution says that AxB is perpendicular to A. Then , what do you think can be the axes for A,B,C. Moreover , please read the post carefully. Don’t you see that there can be a choice for option 1 to be used or 2 or some other maybe. I am not at all getting what you did not get.

Comment: Indeed, the point is to think about what $A \times B$ means. What is it perpendicular to?

Comment: @MattiP. No, you can also think that if A and B lie on the same axis . Then , there is no need to think of what is it perpendicular to . A when parallel or anti parallel to B l A x B = 0

Comment: @S.M.T The usual definition of the cross product $A \times B$ includes the fact that it is orthogonal to both $A$ and $B$. That is a property of the vectors, regardless of any axes or systems of coordinates. If you are using a different definition please write that into the question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bar A\times \bar B = \bar C$$
Now, $\bar C$ must be a vector that is perpendicular to both vectors $\bar A$ and $\bar B$

Now, the dot product of vector $\bar C$ with $\bar A$ or $\bar B$ must be zero
as
$\bar a. \bar b = |a|\times|b|\times \cos\theta$
which here angle between $\bar C$ and $\bar A$ is $90^0$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a very tricky property of [Triple Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product.) defined as $$[A\ B\ C]=A\cdot (B\times C),$$ where $A,B,C$ are vector quantities, we can prove your problem in a single line.

The property is $$[A\ B\ C]=[B\ C\ A]=[C\ A\ B].$$
Now you have given $[A\ A\ B]=[B\ A\ A]=B\cdot (A\times A)=0$ since $A\times A=0$.